# Range-based loop over an input stream

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, inputstream

To iterate over an input stream, we would usually use a `std::istream_iterator` like so:

```
typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string> input_iterator;

std::ifstream file("myfile");
for (input_iterator i(file); i != input_iterator(); i++) {
  // Here, *i denotes each element extracted from the file
}
```

It'd be nice if we could use the range-based `for` statement to iterate over input streams. However, for objects of class type, range-based `for` requires the object to have `begin()` and `end()` member functions (§6.5.4, bold emphasis added):

> - if `_RangeT` is an array type, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `__range` and `__range + __bound`, respectively, where `__bound` is the array bound. If `_RangeT` is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
> - **if `_RangeT` is a class type**, the *unqualified-ids* `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`, respectively;
> - otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2). For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace `std` is an associated namespace.

The input streams don't have these member functions (they are not Containers) and so range-based `for` won't work on them. This makes sense anyway because you would need some way to specify the type to extract (`std::string` in the case above).

But if we know what we want to extract, is it possible to define our own `begin()` and `end()` functions (perhaps specializations or overloads of `std::begin()` and `std::end()`) for input streams such that they would be found by class member access lookup as described above?

It's unclear (at least to me) from §6.5.4 whether the functions will then be looked up with argument-dependent lookup if the previous lookup fails. Another thing to consider is that `std::ios_base` and its derivatives already have a member called `end` which is a flag for seeking.

Here's the intended result:

```
std::ifstream file("myfile");
for (const std::string& str : file) {
  // Here, str denotes each element extracted from the file
}
```

Or:

```
std::ifstream file("myfile");
for (auto i = begin(file); i != end(file); i++) {
  // Here, *i denotes each element extracted from the file
}
```

Comment: Is it just me, or is that pretty unclear from the spec? It seems like `std::begin()` and `std::end()` would only be found if `_RangeT` is not of array or class type.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the best wording, but I think you are intended to read it as "if it's a class AND it has .begin and .end then it will use those... otherwise", i.e. you can provide the free functions.

Comment: "*`begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class _RangeT ... and if **either ... finds at least one declaration**, `begin-expr` and `end-expr` are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`*" - since `std::ios_base::end` does exist (and thus `std::ifstream::end` will be found) the game is up. `.begin()` won't be found, and `.end()` will be a syntax error.

Comment: FWIW Boost.Range provides an [`istream_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/istream_range.html). [Demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/30d23bd6b0d73eeef5a4d29d3163c9a3).

Answer (score 7):

An obvious approach is to use a simple decorator for your stream providing the type and the necessary interface. Here is how this could look like:

```
template <typename T>
struct irange
{
    irange(std::istream& in): d_in(in) {}
    std::istream& d_in;
};
template <typename T>
std::istream_iterator<T> begin(irange<T> r) {
    return std::istream_iterator<T>(r.d_in);
}
template <typename T>
std::istream_iterator<T> end(irange<T>) {
    return std::istream_iterator<T>();
}

for (auto const& x: irange<std::string>(std::ifstream("file") >> std::skipws)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether they will be found by argument-dependent lookup, because you are allowed to put specializations of classes and functions in the `std` namespace.

Comment: But, as far as I'm aware, you are not allowed to add overloads, and since you cannot partially specialise functions, you'd either need to add full specialisations for all `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` or just add specialisations for the one(s) you need.

Comment: @PeterAlexander uh, I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "full specialisations for all `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`?

Comment: @PeterAlexander Surely we'll need a specialisation for `std::basic_istream`?

Comment: Ignore me, for some reason I thought the `begin`/`end` would take a `std::istream_iterator<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution. Sadly, it does require an extra structure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct S {
  std::istream& is;
  typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string> It;
  S(std::istream& is) : is(is) {}
  It begin() { return It(is); }
  It end() { return It(); }
};

int main () {
  std::ifstream file("myfile");
  for(auto& string : S(file)) {
    std::cout << string << "\n";
  }
}
```

Another solution is to derive from `std::ifstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>


struct ifstream : std::ifstream {
  // using std::ifstream::ifstream; I wish g++4.7 supported inheriting constructors!
  ifstream(const char* fn) : std::ifstream(fn) {}
  typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string> It;
  It begin() { return It(*this); }
  It end() { return It(); }
};

int main () {
  ifstream file("myfile");
  for(auto& string : file) {
    std::cout << string << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to pursue the idea of specializing `std::begin` and `std::end` for classes derived  from `std::basic_istream` (I'm not so great at this template metaprogramming business):

```
namespace std
{
  template <typename C>
  typename
  std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<std::basic_istream<typename C::char_type>, C>::value,
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>>::type
  begin(C& c)
  {
    return {c};
  }

  template <typename C>
  typename
  std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<std::basic_istream<typename C::char_type>, C>::value,
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>>::type
  end(C& c)
  {
    return {};
  }
}
```

Actually, it works pretty well. I didn't create versions that take `const C&` because I don't think it makes sense to extract from a const stream (and I had errors when I tried to do so). I'm also not sure if I can make this more move friendly. So now I can print out the contents of `myfile` like so::

```
std::ifstream file("myfile");
std::copy(begin(file), end(file), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

So these `begin` and `end` functions work as expected. However, it falls flat when used in a range-based `for` loop. `std::basic_istream` classes are derived from `std::ios_base` which already has a member called `end` (it's a flag for seeking within a stream). Once the range-based `for` loop finds this, it just gives up because it can't find a corresponding `begin` (not to mention that `end` is not the right kind of entity):

> main.cpp:35:33: error: range-based ‘for’ expression of type ‘std::basic_ifstream’ has an ‘end’ member but not a ‘begin’

The only alternative that works in both situations, as others have mentioned, is to create a wrapper object. Unfortunately that `end` member in `std::ios_base` completely ruins any chance of implementing this in a nice way.