# Avoiding or improving brute force method: Counting character repetition from all words in a dictionary text file

Tags: c++, performance, c++17, brute-force

I wrote this utility function that will take the contents of a alpha dictionary file and will add up the repetition count of each letter or character of the alphabet.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// this function just generates a map of each of the alphabet's
// character position within the alphabet. 
void initCharIndexMap( std::map<unsigned, char>& index ) {
    char c = 'a';
    for ( unsigned i = 1; i < 27; i++ ) {
        index[i] = c;
        c++;
    }
} 

void countCharacterRepetition( std::vector<std::string>& words, const std::map<unsigned, char> index, std::map<char, unsigned>& weights ) {
    unsigned count = 0;

    for ( auto& s : words ) {
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower );

        for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ ) {
            using It = std::map<unsigned, char>::const_iterator;
            for ( It it = index.cbegin(); it != index.cend(); ++it ) {
                if ( s[i] == it->second ) {
                    count++;
                    weights[it->second] += count;
                }
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string line;

    std::ifstream file;
    file.open( "words_alpha.txt" );

    while( std::getline( file, line )
        words.push_back(line);

    std::map<unsigned, char> index;
    initCharIndexMap(index);

    std::map<char, unsigned> weights;
    countCharRepetition(words, index, weights);

    for (auto& w : weights)
        std::cout << w.first << ' ' << w.second << '\n';

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

It gives me this output which appears to be valid at first glance:

```
a 295794
b 63940
c 152980
d 113190
e 376455
f 39238
g 82627
h 92369
i 313008
j 5456
k 26814
l 194915
m 105208
n 251435
o 251596
p 113662
q 5883
r 246141
s 250284
t 230895
u 131495
v 33075
w 22407
x 10493
y 70578
z 14757
```

The dictionary text file that I am using can be found from this [github](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) page.

This appears to be working. It took about 3 minutes to process on my current machine which isn't horrible, however, this seems like a `brute force` approach. Is there a more efficient way of doing a task like this?

Comment: You maybe better off asking at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) regarding performance improvements of already working code.

Comment: For a dense index of size 27, an array could express the mapping easier than a map; and if the mapping can be derived through `i-'a'` anyway, you will not even need an explicit mapping table.

Comment: Further, why store all lines and process then rather than processing each line directly?

Comment: The intermediate vector seems like a giant waste of time/space. Just reap the words and pump their lower-cased characters into a counter table of size `unsigned int count[1 << CHAR_BIT] ] {0};` . how you report the results is somewhat an afterthought from there. The only C++ standard container i see needed here is the `std::string` itself.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all of the feedback. I can now take what I already have and try to put your suggestions to use!

Comment: As a side note: eventually I want each character of the alphabet to be associated with either a pair or a tuple of two unsigned values. The first being the index into its alphabetic position and the second it's weighted or occurrence value. So I might end up having something like this: `std::map<char, std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>>`

Comment: Note that the lowercase letters are not guaranteed to be contiguous and increasing. The initialization function works for ASCII, but if you ever ran this on a machine that uses EBCDIC you'd get strange-looking results, because EBCDIC has some non-alphabetic characters in the middle of the alphabet.

Comment: Did you compile your program with optimizations enabled? The 3min runtime seems long and may be shorter if you let your compiler stretch its legs and optimize the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just counting how many times each character appears, then all you need is this:

```c++
int frequency[26] = {};
for (auto const& str : words) {
  for (int i=0; i<str.size(); i++) {
    frequency[tolower(str[i]) - 'a']++;
  }
}

for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
  cout << char(i + 'a') << " " << frequency[i] << endl;
}
```

If you want to include upper and lowercase characters, change the array size to 90, remove the `tolower` call, and change your loop so that it prints only if `i` is between `a` and `z` or `A` and `Z`.

Comment: For my purposes `a` and `A` are the same letter and the appearance of either is a repetition count.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just going for performance, I would say you still have to read in the file char by char - but I think all the searching is processing that could be optimised.

I would say the following pseudo code should be faster (I'll try and knock up an example later):

```
void read_dictionary(char *fileName)
{
    // Pre-sized array (faster access)
    std::array<int, 26> alphabet_count = {0};

    // Open the file
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return; //could not open file

    // Read through the file
    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        // If it is a letter a-z
        if ( ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) ||
        {
             // Increment the array value for that letter
             ++alphabet_count[c - 'a'];
        }
        // else if letter A-Z
        else if ( ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) ||
        {
             // Increment the array value for that letter
             ++alphabet_count[c - 'A'];
        }
    }
}
```

The point here is that we are not searching for matches we are using the char value to index into the array to increment the alphabet letter

Answer (score 1):

All of the aforementioned answers assume continuity between `a` and `z`, and [history will tell you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) that is *not* always the case. A solution doesn't need to assume this, and can still be efficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <climits>
#include <cctype>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    unsigned int count[1U << CHAR_BIT] {};

    std::ifstream inp(argv[1]);
    for (std::istream_iterator<char> it(inp), it_eof; it != it_eof; ++it)
        ++count[ std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)) ];

    for (unsigned i=0; i<(1U << CHAR_BIT); ++i)
    {
        if (std::isalpha(i) && count[i])
            std::cout << static_cast<char>(i) << ' ' << count[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[~ user]$ clang++ --std=c++14 -O2 -o main main.cpp
[~ user] time ./main /usr/share/dict/words 
a 199554
b 40433
c 103440
d 68191
e 235331
f 24165
g 47094
h 64356
i 201032
j 3167
k 16158
l 130463
m 70680
n 158743
o 170692
p 78163
q 3734
r 160985
s 139542
t 152831
u 87353
v 20177
w 13864
x 6932
y 51681
z 8460

real    0m0.085s
user    0m0.073s
sys     0m0.005s
```

That would probably be sufficiently fast enough for your application, whatever it is.

Comment: When I get more time I'll have to test this out on my own. I like this answer the best so far for it also solves the issue of being more generic to where I'm not relying specifically on `ASCII` encoding. After I test this if all goes well I will more than likely accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open( "words_alpha.txt" );

    char c;
    std::array<std::size_t, 26> counts {};

    while( file >> c)
        ++counts[c-'a'];

    for(char c = 0; c<26;++c)
        std::cout<<'('<<c+'a'<<','<<counts[c]<<")\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version keeps track of words unnecessarily: you're simply counting characters in a file. The separation into words and lines doesn't matter. It's also unnecessary to store the words.

You could aim for readable high-level code and write something like this:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/letter-count-56498637
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
//*

int main() {
   Histogram<char, 'a', 'z'> counts;

   std::ifstream file;
   file.open("words_alpha.txt");

   for (auto ch : make_range<char>(file)) counts.count(tolower(ch));

   for (auto c : std::as_const(counts)) std::cout << c.value << ' ' << c.count << '\n';
}
```

This is the bare minimum of how modern C++ code should look

This requires the `Histogram` class, and a `make_range` adapter for input streams. You can't merely implement `std::begin` and `std::end` for `std::ifstream`, because the member `end()` function takes precedence and interferes (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13039796/1329652)). The code below is the fragment marked //* above.

```
template <typename T>
void saturating_inc(T &val) {
   if (val < std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) val++;
}

template <typename T, T min, T max>
class Histogram {
   using counter_type = unsigned;
   using storage_type = std::vector<counter_type>;
   storage_type counts;

  public:
   template <typename U>
   void count(U val) {
      if (val >= min && val <= max) saturating_inc(counts[size_t(val - min)]);
   }
   Histogram() : counts(1 + max - min) {}
   struct element {
      T value;
      counter_type count;
   };

   class const_iterator {
      T val;
      storage_type::const_iterator it;

     public:
      const_iterator(T val, storage_type::const_iterator it) : val(val), it(it) {}
      const_iterator &operator++() {
         ++val;
         ++it;
         return *this;
      }
      bool operator!=(const const_iterator &o) const { return it != o.it; }
      element operator*() const { return {val, *it}; }
   };
   const_iterator begin() const { return {min, counts.begin()}; }
   const_iterator end() const { return {0, counts.end()}; }
};

template <class C, class T>
class istream_range {
   C &ref;

  public:
   istream_range(C &ref) : ref(ref) {}
   std::istream_iterator<T> begin() { return {ref}; }
   std::istream_iterator<T> end() { return {}; }
};

template <class T, class C>
istream_range<C, T> make_range(C &ref) {
   return {ref};
}
```

This concludes the example.